# How to remove the JSON array element in Android

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

```
 { "Employee" :  
        [  
         {"id":"101","name":"Sonoo Jaiswal","salary":"50000"},  
         {"id":"102","name":"Vimal Jaiswal","salary":"60000"}  
        ]   
    }  

for (int i =0;i< json_array.length(); i++) {
     json_array.remove(i);
  }
```

I  have one sample JSONArray data. I want to remove the whole json array with certain condition.
But `json_array.remove(position)` method is not working. Is there any other way to remove the whole JSON array or element in Android?

Comment: "JSONArray .remove(position) is not working" What do you mean by "not working"? Please post the code you are using.

Comment: jsonarray.remove(position) method is not working in API level. whether its deprecated or any other way to remove jsonarray.

Comment: "is not working in API level" What do you mean by "not working" and "in API level"? Please post the code you are using.

Comment: post your entire code

Answer (score 3):

If you iterate forwards through an array by index, removing elements, you will always miss the element after the one you have just removed.

Think about the array `[A, B, C]`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  arr.remove(i);
}
```

- On the first iteration, `i == 0`, so `arr.remove(i)` will remove `A`; the array is now `[B, C]`
- On the second iteration, `i == 1`, so `arr.remove(i)` will remove `C`; the array is now `[B]`.
- On the third iteration, `i == 2`, which is beyond the length of the array, so the loop stops.

Your final array is `[B]`, not `[]`.

Iterate in reverse:

```
 for (int i =json_array.length() - 1;i >= 0; i--) {
   json_array.remove(i);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to remove the whole json array with certain condition

Then no need to use `for-loop` for removing items from `JSONArray`, just remove whole `Employee` `JSONArray` from `JSONObject` using `Employee` key:

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(<json_string>);
jsonObject.remove("Employee"); //<< pass JSONArray name here
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below is another you can do this**

```
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();     
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonstring); 
int len = jsonArray.length();
    if (jsonArray != null) { 
       for (int i=0;i<len;i++)
       { 
        //Excluding the item at position
        if (i != position) 
        {
            list.put(jsonArray.get(i));
        }
    } 
    //Remove the element from arraylist
    list.remove(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a while loop across the length of the json_array and at each time delete the first index. the loop will reach a stage when the length of the json_array is zero to show the json_array is not empty and and cleared.

```
while (json_array.length() > 0) {
        json_array.remove(0)
}
```